# #only server-side# How to get the echo-html-div-result of the php code saved to png-file on this server?

Tags: php, png

Like a Log-file is written by a php-script via `fwrite($fp, ---HTML---)`,

I need to save an HTML DIV as png-file on the server.
The client-browser only start the php-script,
but without any client-interaction the png-file should be saved on the server.
Is there a way to do this?

All posts (over thousands) I have been reading are about html2canvas,
which is (as I understand) client-side operating.
I know the html-(html-div)-rendering normally does the browser.[=client-side]

But is there a way to do it in PHP on server-side ?

Reason:

Until now the procedure is
print the div via browser on paper twice
one for the costumer,
one to scan it in again to save it on the server as picture and throw it in the paperbasket.

By more than 500 times a day ...

By security reasons it need to be a saved picture on the server.

Comment: You probably need to use a browser emulator like Selenium.

Comment: @Barmar - 1st Thanks for formatting. 2nd I am more a server-user than a server-programmer. I use xampp and I don't have installed any software on it. Until now for many tasks I finally found easy solutions. BUT the next days I will google for browser emulators, too.